# Compute norm of linear functional over $c_0$

Tags: operator-theory

I am given a functional $f$, that is defined as
\begin{align} 
f:c_0 &\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\ 
x &\mapsto \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\xi_k}{3^k} ~~~x = (\xi_k)_{k\ge1} 
\end{align}
and I am supposed to calculate ||f||.

I started by estimating an upper bound for $||fx||$:

$$
||fx|| = \left| \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\xi_k}{3^k} \right| 
\le \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left| \frac{\xi_k}{3^k} \right|
\le \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sup_\limits{k \ge 1} |\xi_k|}{3^k}
\le ||x|| \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 3^{-k}
\le \frac{1}{2} ||x||
$$

This tells me that $||f|| \le \frac{1}{2}$. So now I'd like to show that there exists an $x$ such that $||f|| \ge \frac{1}{2}$, but I can't find a suitable $x$ to do the job. Am I approaching this problem the wrong way or is there some obvious $x$ that I'm somehow not seeing?

Comment: What is the norm on $c_0$

Comment: If $x = (\xi_k)_{k \ge 1}$ then the norm is $||x|| = \sup_\limits{k \ge 1} |\xi_k|$

Comment: If $f$ is a non-$0$ functional on an infinite-dimensional normed vector space (or Banach space) $X,$ there does not necessarily exist $x\in X$ with $|f(x)|=\|f\| \cdot \|x\|\ne 0$..... (LaTex |f(x)|=\|f(x)\| \cdot \|x\| \ne 0.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take the sequences $a^n = (1,1,\underbrace{...}_{n\text{ times}},1,0,0,...)$

Comment: Also, note that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}3^{-j} = \frac{1}{2}$ not $\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: Oh right, I was looking at the sum from 0 to infinity; my bad. Now to your solution, do I need to use $x = \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty} a^n$? Edit: Yes I do. I would upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation yet.